# Problem in getting months in ceiling or floor in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I am trying to get number of months between two dates.

I want the solution like this:

- if output came to 4.2 months, then return 4 months
- if output came to 4.5 months, then return 5 months
- if output came to 4.9 months, then return 5 months

Comment: i have tried below functions but desired output is not coming:
DATEDIFF(dd,OPENDATE,MATURITYDATE)/30 , DATEDIFF(mm,OPENDATE,MATURITYDATE)

Comment: There are many different days in a month like Jun 31 Feb 28 or 29. What's your logic to get days of month numbe?

Comment: i am simply assuming days of month to be 30 days. my query is  that if there are 135 days then the number of months are coming 4.5 months. i want it to be 5 months(ceiling of 4.5, or in other case floor if months are 4.2 )

Comment: Ok I got it, you can try my answer:)

Comment: For example, if the dates are 2018-01-01 and 2018-01-16.  That's 15 days, so you would want 0.5 rounded up to 1 in this case.  Another way to look at it is that 15 days of passed in a month of 31 days, so that's 15/31 months, which would round down to 0.

Comment: I know you specified assuming a month to be 30 days, but I have to ask.  I've spent a lot of time educating users on the consequences of their definition of "months between two dates".  Every user has a different definition.  Consider May 1, 2018 through Aug 16, 2029.  Fewer than 136 months have passed, but if you assume 30 days per month, you'll get 138 months. Just want to make sure you know what you're asking. No disrespect intended if you've already considered this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are assuming days of month to be 30 days.

`DATEDIFF` return `integer` difference days.

So, you can try to use `CAST(days as decimal)` let the day number be float number, then do `ROUND` get your result.

```
select ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(dd,OPENDATE,MATURITYDATE)as decimal) /30,0 )
from T
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=07e3306b12dc8ee2ede7524fde69a287)